# Venn diagram method?

Tags: probability

I'm not that bad at Venn diagram but I got confused on this question.

At a college, $90$ percent of students who take physics also take math and $60$ percent of students who take math also take physics. If $30$ percent of students at the college take physics, what percent of students take math?

I don't mind to learn a new way to do this kind of problems except sketching venn diagram. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you calculated the percentage of students who take both physics and math?

Comment: Not much to do with Venn Diagrams: $M$ = math, $Y$ = phy:. $0.9 = P(M|Y) = P(MY)/P(Y) = P(MY)/0.3.$ Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be the number of students at the college, let $p$ be the number of students taking physics, and let $m$ be the number of students taking math. Then:

- $p = 0.3n$ students take physics.
- Out of these $p$ physics students, $0.9p$ of them also take math.
- But we also know that $0.6m$ students take both physics and math so that $0.6m = 0.9p$.

Thus, we find that:
$$
\frac{m}{n}
= \frac{0.6m}{0.6n}
= \frac{0.9p}{0.6n}
= \frac{0.9(0.3n)}{0.6n}
= 0.45
$$
So $45\%$ of students take math.